# Why is Mathematica faster than CDF Player?

Tags: performance-tuning, cdfplayer

Yesterday I downloaded and installed CDF Player 11 (the free version), then made a little .cdf document to test it. The code is just this:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 5}, AspectRatio -> Automatic], {a, 1,10}, 
{b, 0, \[Pi]}]
```

I noticed that when moving the cursors in Mathematica, the curve changes fast and smoothly, however, dynamic updating appears to be much slower in CDF Player. Why is this happening and how can I possibly improve the code to run in it ?

Edit: I am running it on Gigabyte Sabre 17, Windows 10 Home, Mathematica 11.

As I stated above, dynamic updating is smoother in Mathematica, and more choppy in CDF Player.

Comment: They shouldn't differ in speed. On my machine the same code runs identically fast from Mathematica and when ran in the free CDF player.

Comment: If you are seeing differences it is likely specific to your machine, and we would need more information to properly have any idea what's going on,

Comment: @user6014 Edited it.